# amd gpu flip error

Tags: drivers, xorg, amdgpu

x.org log and kern log filling with errors.

Video timing out for a minute or so when using caja. But, eventually recovers.

xlog errors are:
[   517.976] Failed to get FB for flip
[   517.976] (WW) AMDGPU(0): Page flip failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
[   517.976] (EE) AMDGPU(0): present flip failed

I found a posting below, but I do not have xf86-video-amdgpu.
   Michel Dänzer @daenzer added radeonsi label 3 months ago
    Developer

```
FWIW, the Xorg log file should no longer get flooded with xf86-video-amdgpu 19.1.0.
```

---

I am running:Ubuntu 19.10
Kernel Linux 5.3.0-42-generic x86_64
mate 1.22.2
'video' installed:

```
i A gnome-video-effects - Collection of GStreamer effects
i A xserver-xorg-video-all - X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
i A xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu - X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
i  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04 - Transitional package for xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04
i A xserver-xorg-video-ati - X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
i A xserver-xorg-video-fbdev - X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
i A xserver-xorg-video-intel - X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
i A xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
i A xserver-xorg-video-qxl - X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
i A xserver-xorg-video-radeon - X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
i A xserver-xorg-video-vesa - X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
i A xserver-xorg-video-vmware - X.Org X server -- VMware display driver

and
i A amd64-microcode - Processor microcode firmware for AMD CPUs
```

Any help, pointers appreciated.
Jay

Comment: I am having this same issue on 18.04.04 LTS.  Video works ok but I am being flooded with these flip messages.  Tried several video cards, all new.  Also does it with the onboard GPU (NVIDIA) driver.